# Why does PHP-FPM need a reverse proxy?

Tags: php, reverse-proxy, reverse

I was reading through the PHP page on Docker Hub and finally got down to the nether-regions where they talk about the different variations of images. When they talk about the FPM variation it says:

> In order to use this image variant, some kind of reverse proxy (such as NGINX, Apache, or other tool which speaks the FastCGI protocol) will be required.

I'm not new to PHP development, however I am not a sysadmin and I don't configure servers very often. When I do, I generally stick with what I know. I use PHP, Apache, and Debian Docker images for development. I write a compose file, and Bob's you uncle. Stuff gets done!

I say this because I don't consider myself a noob after 10+ years of programming and web development experience. But, I've found a hole in my knowledge and can't seem to find a clear answer to my question.

Why does PHP-FPM need a reverse proxy? What's different about the PHP-FPM implementation that it cant run on an Apache server? Or, am I completely misunderstanding what FPM is?

I appreciate any info anyone can contribute. I'm sure others out there would benefit from this info, as well.

Comment: When you say you use Apache and PHP, what it your configuration on apache ? I have not use Apache since a while, Tthe most common usage was php mode on apache. It is binary packaging of php spawn and control by Apache. It is highly couple with apache In opposition with  FPM which  prupose to have a different daemon to pilot PHP, Webserver will only proxy request to this "Agent" As we will do for most of other web tech.

Comment: FPM speaks FastCGI, not HTTP. You need something in the middle that speaks both, eg: Nginx, Apache, etc.

Comment: @Sammitch That clears up some of the confusion but it also brings up another question.  If Apache speaks both HTTP and FastCGI why would I need a proxy? Can't PHP and PHP-FPM just be installed on the same 'machine'/container/OS with an Apache server without having to have a proxy?  --just curious

Comment: @Yanis-git So, if I understand you correctly, mod_php is Apache's module for interpreting PHP and PHP-FPM is an alternative to mod_php.  Is that correct?
BTW: It's nice to come back to PHP after a few years and have a new fresh perspective. I see things very differently and recognize the holes in my knowledge. Just goes to show that everyone can learn something new.

Answer (score 0):

@Sammitch and @Yanis-git gave good answers in the comments, above. Too bad they didn't post their comments as answers. I would have selected one as the answer.